# How to serialize request data before sending ajax post request to server using Jquery form plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using [Jquery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) send post request with form data to server. I want request to be sent as JSON object. If I used just .ajax function I would have set data option to something like `data: JSON.stringify(formData, null, 2)` but since pugin gathers data for me I have this question: how to modify(serialize) request data before sending?

**upd** There is an API for this called `.formSerialize()` but I do not know where to apply it. If uncomment the commented line, I am redirected to a page with server response. Otherwise post works fine.

How do I pass `.formSerialize()` results to `.ajaxSubmit()`?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    function create_post() {
        var options = { 
            type:      'post',     
            enctype:       "multipart/form-data",
            dataType:  'json',
            // data: $('#post-form').formSerialize(); 

            success : function(json) {
                    $("#id_img").attr('src', json.img_url)
                    console.log("success"); 
                    );
                },

            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                    " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); 
                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            } 
        }; 


        $('#post-form').ajaxSubmit(options); 
    };  

    $('#post-form').on('submit', function(event){   
        create_post();
        return false;
    });

});
```

**server Django views.py**

```
def edit_ajax(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        """...work with request data..."""

        return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps({'img_url': person.ava.thumbnail.url}),
                content_type="application/json"
            )

    return HttpResponse("You shouldn't have come here.")
```

Comment: [**Check their API**](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api) — they already have documentation on how to selectively serialize form data.

Comment: There is a formSerialize() API function which returnes serialized form string. But where do I apply this string to?